# vertical alignment using tabularx / arraystretch

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx

I am using the tabularx package to customize my tables. I changed the definition of `tabularxcolumn` to vertically center the text. As I am using `arraystretch`, the bold 'titles' of my table are aligned quite ugly. How can I fix this?

```
  \documentclass[fleqn,10pt,twocolumn]{article} % Document font size and equations 
  \usepackage{tabularx}
  \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
  \usepackage{colortbl}
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5} \setlength\minrowclearance{2.4pt} 

  \arrayrulecolor{blue}

  \newcolumntype{=}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
  \newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
  \newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
    #1\ignorespaces
  }


  \begin{document}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|=l^X|@{}}
  \multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor{blue}}c}{\color{white}\textbf{Table: Interfaces}} \\
  \hline
  \rowcolor{blue}
  \rowstyle{\color{white}\bfseries}
  \textbf{Interface} &\rowstyle{\color{white}}\textbf{Programming Languages}\\
  \texttt{.NET}
   & The blablab this is only some text to illustrate my problem:
   \begin{itemize}[topsep=-5pt,leftmargin=0.7cm,itemsep=0.8pt,labelsep=.5cm]
   \item C\#
   \item VB .NET
   \end{itemize}\\
  \texttt{JNI}
  & Some other text \\
   \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \end{document}
```

And can someone explain when I need to insert this @{}? I still dont get that..

Comment: Related/see: [Column padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You had

```
Overfull \hbox (10.00002pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 34--35
```

As your table was full width but indented by paragraph indent (10pt) I added `\noindent`.

You do not *have* to use `@{}` ever but if you do use it (or `|`) you need to be consistent. `|` adds a rule and `@{}` removes the usual inter-column padding which by default also appears before the first and after the last column. If you use these you need to use them also in the `\multicolumn` specifications so that the spanning columns get the same inter-column space as the columns they span.

(*update* Note the use of an `l` cell to ensure baseline alignment of the headings)

It's a bit unusual to put `Table:..` *in* the table rather than have a separate caption, but I left it like that:

```
 \documentclass[fleqn,10pt,twocolumn]{article} % Document font size and equations 
  \usepackage{tabularx}
  \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
  \usepackage{colortbl}
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5} \setlength\minrowclearance{2.4pt} 

  \arrayrulecolor{blue}

  \newcolumntype{=}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
  \newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
  \newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
    #1\ignorespaces
  }


  \begin{document}

  \noindent X\dotfill X

  \noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}|=l^X|@{}}
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}|>{\columncolor{blue}}c|@{}}{\color{white}\textbf{Table: Interfaces}} \\
  \hline
  \rowcolor{blue}
  \rowstyle{\color{white}\bfseries}
  \textbf{Interface} &\multicolumn{1}{l|@{}}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Programming Languages}}}\\
  \texttt{.NET}
   & The blablab this is only some text to illustrate my problem:
   \begin{itemize}[topsep=-5pt,leftmargin=0.7cm,itemsep=0.8pt,labelsep=.5cm]
   \item C\#
   \item VB .NET
   \end{itemize}\\
  \texttt{JNI}
  & Some other text \\
   \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: But "Programming Languages" still seems to be nearer to the bottom line than "Interfaces"...

Comment: @Kathiieee so it is put `\strut` before each (it is the depth of the `g` you need to hide)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- maybe i'm confused here, but if it were the depth of the `g` that needed to be hidden, then "Interface" (which has no descenders) would be *lower* than "Programming".  ???

Comment: @Kathiieee sorry, see update.

Comment: @barbarabeeton you are not confused, I was dashing out of the door (and wrong). See update.