# create a table with different colors

Tags: tables, color

How is it possible to create a table as that given below?
Of course I want just the basic idea of how achieving the very structure and not the typesetting of the contents:-!)
[image]

Comment: Look at the `tcolorbox` package. That does those backgrounds for you. The rest are very basics in LaTeX.

Comment: However, we would like to have the basic idea of a MWE :):):) Look at `tcolorbox` package.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tcolorbox}



\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\tcbox[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black]{
    Micromorphic media
}
&
\parbox{3in}{\begin{itemize}
\item Kinematics
\item Energy
\end{itemize}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. But the alignement is not the same as the original.

Comment: For that, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122266/vertical-alignment-using-tabularx-arraystretch