# Drawing a "table" with captions on the left and mixed content (tikz and code listings) on the right

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I have some fairly specific requirements. I'm trying to draw a "table" (in quotes because I don't necessarily care if I use the `tabular` environment) with captions (text) on the left, and associated content on the right. The "content" is `tikz` graphs and (in the last row) a code listing.

Here is what I have right now:

```
\begin{figure}
\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X}
    \\[0.5em]

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. &  \\[0.5em]

    \\[0.5em]
    \hline

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. &

    \begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
        \tikzset{vertex/.style = {shape=rectangle,draw,font=\footnotesize}}
        \tikzset{edge/.style = {->,> = latex'}}
        
        \node[vertex] (a) {lorem};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \\[0.5em]
    \hline

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. &

    \begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
        \tikzset{vertex/.style = {shape=rectangle,draw,font=\footnotesize}}
        \tikzset{edge/.style = {->,> = latex'}}
        
        \node[vertex] (a) at (0, 0) {lorem};
        \node[vertex] (b) at (-1, 1) {ipsum};
        \node[vertex] (c) at (1, 1) {dolor};
        
        \draw[edge] (b) to (a);
        \draw[edge] (c) to (a);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \\[0.5em]
    \hline

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. &

    \begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
        \tikzset{vertex/.style = {shape=rectangle,draw,font=\footnotesize}}
        \tikzset{edge/.style = {->,> = latex'}}
        
        \node[vertex] (a) at (0, 0) {lorem};
        \node[vertex] (b) at (-1, 1) {ipsum};
        \node[vertex] (c) at (1, 1) {dolor};
        \node[vertex] (d) at (-1, 2) {sit};
        
        \draw[edge] (b) to (a);
        \draw[edge] (c) to (a);
        \draw[edge] (d) to (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \\[0.5em]
    \hline

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. &

    \begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
        \tikzset{vertex/.style = {shape=rectangle,draw,font=\footnotesize}}
        \tikzset{edge/.style = {->,> = latex'}}
        
        \node[vertex] (a) at (0, 0) {lorem};
        \node[vertex] (b) at (-1, 1) {ipsum};
        \node[vertex] (c) at (1, 1) {dolor};
        \node[vertex] (d) at (-1, 2) {sit};
        \node[vertex] (e) at (1, 2) {amet};
        
        \draw[edge] (b) to (a);
        \draw[edge] (c) to (a);
        \draw[edge] (d) to (b);
        \draw[edge] (e) to (c);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \\[0.5em]
    \hline

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. & 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
        \tikzset{vertex/.style = {shape=rectangle,draw,font=\footnotesize}}
        \tikzset{edge/.style = {->,> = latex'}}
        
        \node[vertex] (a) at (0, 0) {lorem};
        \node[vertex] (b) at (-1, 1) {ipsum};
        \node[vertex] (c) at (1, 1) {dolor};
        \node[vertex] (d) at (-1, 2) {sit};
        \node[vertex] (e) at (1, 2) {amet};
        \node[vertex] (f) at (1, 3) {consectetur};
        
        \draw[edge] (b) to (a);
        \draw[edge] (c) to (a);
        \draw[edge] (d) to (b);
        \draw[edge] (e) to (c);
        \draw[edge] (f) to (e);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \\

    \\[0.5em]
    \hline

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. &
    \begin{lstlisting}^^J
    Lorem ipsum = Dolor.sit();^^J
    Amet consectetur = adipiscing(elit);^^J
    sed.do(eiusmod);^^J
    ^^J
    \end{lstlisting}

\end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is, this renders like this:

[image]

The main problem here is that the content on the right isn't aligned with the caption on the left. The `\hline`s and the frames around the graphs are just here to illustrate, I don't want them in the final product, so it's hard to tell what goes with what, not to mention the table is much taller than it needs to be. It seems like the problem is that the captions aren't aligning to the top of their row.

How can I get what I'm looking for? My requirements are:

1. Align caption and content in sensible way, ideally vertical center to vertical center.
2. Use `tikz` for the graphs.
3. The code block in the last row should look like code, i.e. be in monospaced font.
4. The whole thing is inside a `figure`.

Beyond that, I don't mind what libraries or environments I use.

Comment: The contents of the cells are aligned at their baseline. For text, this is (in this case for `X`) the baseline of the first row. For the Tikzpicture, it is the bottom of the bounding box/the picture. You can use the `baseline` option to set this to any *y* value or to the *y* value of a coordinate/anchor. For TikZ `baseline=(current bounding box.center)` centers the picture vertically.

Comment: The vertical alignment of a `X` column can be changed, too. (See the manual.) [This question seems related.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122266)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to start with. Instead of `tabular`, you can use `sidebyside` tcolorboxes. One for each pair of text+tikzfigure, you can select the width for each part or left the package to do it for you. About the `listing` part, you can use a `tcblisting` box with `comment and listing` type.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.}

\tcbsidebyside[blanker, sidebyside gap = 5mm, halign lower=center]{
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
}{}

\tcbsidebyside[blanker, sidebyside gap = 5mm, halign lower=center]{
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{vertex/.style = {shape=rectangle,draw,font=\footnotesize}}
        \tikzset{edge/.style = {->,> = latex'}}
        
        \node[vertex] (a) {lorem};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\tcbsidebyside[blanker, sidebyside gap = 5mm, halign lower=center, sidebyside adapt=right]{
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{vertex/.style = {shape=rectangle,draw,font=\footnotesize}}
        \tikzset{edge/.style = {->,> = latex'}}
        
        \node[vertex] (a) at (0, 0) {lorem};
        \node[vertex] (b) at (-1, 1) {ipsum};
        \node[vertex] (c) at (1, 1) {dolor};
        
        \draw[edge] (b) to (a);
        \draw[edge] (c) to (a);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{tcblisting}{blanker, comment side listing, 
    comment={Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.},
    righthand width=0.6\linewidth
    }
    Lorem ipsum = Dolor.sit();
    Amet consectetur = adipiscing(elit);
    sed.do(eiusmod);
\end{tcblisting}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to work really well. Do you have any recommendations for how to put a monospace font code block at the bottom?

Comment: @JackM I've updated the answer with a `listing` example. If you decide to go with this solution, please take a look at `tcolorbox` documentation. It offers a lot of options to customize the output.